# InertiaJS keep form data after validation error

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony, inertiajs

In my InertiaJS/VueJS project I have a prop that receive some data from the backend:

```
event: {
  type:    Object,
  default: () => { return {} }
},
```

That's how the event obj looks in the backend:

```
['name' => 'Event Name']
```

I use `toRefs` to convert the reactive prop and update its properties in the UI:

```
const eventRef = toRefs(props).event
```

So the Event has the name 'Event Name' when the component loads, when I update the event name in the UI to 'New Name' and submit the form, I send the `eventRef` obj in the request to create the new event:

```
Inertia.post(url, eventRef, only: ['global'])
```

If there's a validation error in the backend, I return it to the frontend and show the error in the UI (This is working without problems). The problem I have is that Inertia  (or maybe VueJS) is returning the object `eventRef` to his previous state when the component is created. Which means that the `name` property of the `eventRef` changes to 'Event Name' again, instead of staying with 'New Name` that was updated in the UI. I would like to preserve the state of the object after I submit the form. This is my Inertia response:

```
component: "Events/EventNew"
props: {
  global: {} // Global object
}
url: "/app/qa/events/new"
version: null
```

As you can see I'm not even getting the 'event' prop from the backend, so it shouldn't be updated. After reading Inertia docs I thought that a simple `preserveState:true` in the request options would do the job but this is not happening. Every time the server returns an Inertia response, the `eventRef` obj is 'reset'.

What am I missing here? I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same problem using Inertia with Vue2. If I understood correctly, you probably seeing this on a form where you trying to update and entry, right? Your validation is working but the form keeps resetting itself to the previous state. If that's the case, what solved this for me was this:

Instead of using `Inertia.post()` directly, use the **[Inertia Form Helper](https://inertiajs.com/forms#form-helper)** instead

**Vue 2**

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="form.post('/login')">
    <!-- email -->
    <input type="text" v-model="form.email">
    <div v-if="form.errors.email">{{ form.errors.email }}</div>
    <!-- password -->
    <input type="password" v-model="form.password">
    <div v-if="form.errors.password">{{ form.errors.password }}</div>
    <!-- remember me -->
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.remember"> Remember Me
    <!-- submit -->
    <button type="submit" :disabled="form.processing">Login</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: this.$inertia.form({
        email: null,
        password: null,
        remember: false,
      }),
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**Vue 3**

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="form.post('/login')">
    <!-- email -->
    <input type="text" v-model="form.email">
    <div v-if="form.errors.email">{{ form.errors.email }}</div>
    <!-- password -->
    <input type="password" v-model="form.password">
    <div v-if="form.errors.password">{{ form.errors.password }}</div>
    <!-- remember me -->
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.remember"> Remember Me
    <!-- submit -->
    <button type="submit" :disabled="form.processing">Login</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

export default {
  setup () {
    const form = useForm({
      email: null,
      password: null,
      remember: false,
    })

    return { form }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out the problem though. It was the `toRefs` that was updating the prop `event` after the request was sent. I updated the code to a simple reactive object and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was the `toRefs` that was modifying the `props` in the component after the request was sent. Using a `reactive` object was the solution:

```
const eventRef = reactive(props.event)
```